# C# - I want to send WPF InkCanvas to socket(other clients)

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, networking

I want to send InkCanvas Strokes to other clients through the server.

I can't find any hints even when I googled.

1. The client sends packets to the server.
2. The server sends packets received from the client to other clients.
3. Other clients convert packets received from the server to the StrokeCollection type.

**Client Code**

> ```
> public void SendInkCanvas(int roomID, InkCanvas inkCanvas)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
>         inkCanvas.Strokes.Save(memoryStream);
>         memoryStream.Position = 0;
>         memoryStream.Flush();
>
>         Packet packet = new Packet(PacketType.SendInkCanvas, id);
>         packet.data.Add("RoomID", roomID);
>         packet.data.Add("Strokes", memoryStream);
>         socket.Send(packet.ToBytes());
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
>     }
> }
> ```

**Server Code**

> ```
> case PacketType.SendInkCanvas:
>     int roomIDIC = (int)packet.data["RoomID"];
>     packet.senderID = "";
>     packet.data.Remove("RoomID");
>
>     // Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Socket>> roomClient
>     foreach (Socket cli in roomClient[roomIDIC].Values)
>         cli.Send(packet.ToBytes());
>     break;
> ```

**Other Clients Code**

> ```
> DrawInkCanvas.Strokes = new StrokeCollection((MemoryStream)packet.data["Strokes"]);
> ```

**Packet Class**

> ```
> [Serializable]
> public class Packet
> {
>     #region Variable
>     public Dictionary<string, object> data;
>     public int packetInt;
>     public bool packetBool;
>     public string senderID;
>     public PacketType packetType;
>     #endregion
>
>     #region PacketType, SenderID
>     public Packet(PacketType type, string senderID)
>     {
>         data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
>         this.packetType = type;
>         this.senderID = senderID;
>     }
>     #endregion
>
>     #region PacketBytes
>     public Packet(byte[] packetBytes)
>     {
>         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
>         MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(packetBytes);
>         formatter.Binder = new AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder();
>         formatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
>         Packet packet = (Packet)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
>
>         stream.Close();
>
>         this.data = packet.data;
>         this.packetInt = packet.packetInt;
>         this.packetBool = packet.packetBool;
>         this.senderID = packet.senderID;
>         this.packetType = packet.packetType;
>     }
>     #endregion
>
>     #region Packet To Bytes
>     public byte[] ToBytes()
>     {
>         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
>         MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
>         formatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
>         formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
>         byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
>         stream.Close();
>
>         return bytes;
>     }
>     #endregion
> }
>
> #region PacketType
> public enum PacketType
> {
>     SendInkCanvas
> }
> #endregion
> ```

Comment: What error/problem are you experiencing with this code?

Comment: Drawing on InkCanvas from the client does not show to other clients.

Comment: Just a hunch, but I'm not sure you can send an actual `MemoryStream` object like that. Try writing the stream to a `Byte` array first instead of adding actual `MemoryStream` to `packet`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I solved it by adding a byte array to the packet.

Comment: Great. I've added that as an actual answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to send the actual `MemoryStream`.

`MemoryStream` is a reference type, which means other objects are only given a reference to the `MemoryStream`s address in the application memory, instead of being given their own copy of the entire object.

When you execute `packet.data.Add("Strokes", memoryStream);`, what's technically added to the dictionary is the address of the `MemoryStream` object. So when you `ToBytes()` and serialize the `Packet` (and the `data` field along with it) only the memory address of the `MemoryStream` gets serialized, not the actual contents. When the `Packet` is deserialized, that existing `MemoryStream` isn't accessible from the new context.

What you want to do instead is add the *content* of the `MemoryStream` to the `Packet`. To do this, you write the `MemoryStream` to a `Byte` array, then add that to `data` instead. `Byte` is a value type, as opposed to a reference type, so it's entire value is copied into `data` and will be serialized along with it.